# What 's meaning of " Business fit, not best in class "?

Tags: meaning

I have seen in a HR magazine that "HR should focus on 'business fit, not best in class', says Panasonic HRD ". and i dont understand what is " business fit" and what's "best in class ". Please help me ! ^_^

Comment: Here is my guess:

Business fit: have the skills required to work in the field you studied.

Best in class: excellent academic performance, but not always capable of transferring knowledge to the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like "HR should focus of meeting the business needs rather than being the best at particular activities"

Answer (score 2):

This means simply that HR should focus on finding candidates for positions who are a good fit for the company, not spend time looking for the very best person to fill a role.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase means that HR selection should be based on how effective or efficient the candidate will be to the organization and the role he is employed for, and not the grade or necessarily the best in academics or the credentials he or she possesses.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of business-speak and won't have a precise definition, with individuals probably using it in slightly different ways.  But almost certainly "business fit" means how well the individual's skills complement the existing business/team.  "Best in class" is idiomatic for top-performing.   The advice from the Panasonic person is don't hire people based on their standalone qualifications,  but think about the existing business and what skills need to be added.